# Use of Symbol in UIFont

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts, uilabel, uifont

The UIFont I use supports the symbol I want. How programmatically can I type that symbol in the code?

```
UILabel *label = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:frame];
scoreLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(20.0)];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", text];
[self addSubview:label];
```

Comment: You never said what the symbol is. If text contains the symbol and is an `NSString` then you need to change `%d` to `%@`

Comment: I need division and multiplication symbols labeled as 247 and 215 on this table http://www.font-cat.com/font_img_big_14x16.php?font_id=617 for Arial Rounded MT Bold font

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually just paste the symbol right into the source code. All of Mac OS X's tools support UTF8 in source code.

So this is perfectly legitimate:

```
NSString *qa = @"6 ÷ 2 = 3";
```

You can enter the ÷ symbol using option-slash, or use Mac OS X's character viewer and double click it.

That said, I don't really trust that everything I use is going to support UTF8 properly. So for myself, I use **unicode escape sequences**. For instance:

```
NSString *qa = @"6 \u00F7 2 = 3";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the Unicode value for it and instead of %d use the following:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", 0x1234];
```

Where the 0x1234 is the Unicode value in Hexadecimal.

Comment: label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", 0x247]; - produces letter G instead of division sign. See my comment above about the table I refer to.

Comment: No you are mixing between Decimal values (base 10) and Hexadecimal (base 16). The code I provided here is for Unicode in Hexadecimal while the 247 you want is in base 10, so please convert 247 to base 16 the answer will be 0xF7. Try this value and you will get the symbol you want.

Comment: For some reason 0xF7 gives me ~ sign

Comment: Please be sure to use **CAPITAL LETTER C** for the `%C` not `%c`. I just tested it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
unichar myCharacter = 247; // DIVISION SIGN
label.text = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&myCharacter length:1];
```

Comment: where to find division and multiplication signs (see my comment above)? Thanks

Comment: There are lots of web sites that let you search the Unicode character tables.  For example, http://www.mclean.net.nz/ucf/ http://unicodelookup.com/ http://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex.html

Comment: The table you linked uses Unicode character numbers.  So the symbols you want are character numbers 215 and 247.  You don't have to convert them to hexadecimal.